# C++ using this to use accessor

Tags: c++, this

I have built an accessor in my class SparseMatrix. I am trying to write a member function `symmetric` and I would like to get access using my accessor to the class private data in my symmetric function.

I have a transpose member function and `this->transpose()` works as I thought. So I tried `this->[]` and of course it doesn't work. Probably because it's operator overloading.

```cpp
bool SparseMatrix::symmetric() const
{
  SparseMatrix A_T(m_m,m_n);
  A_T = this->transpose();
  bool is_symmetric;
  for (int row=0; row<m_m; ++row)
    {
      int cols = A_T.m_colIndex[row].size();
      for (int col=0; col<cols; ++col)
        {
          array<int, 2> A_tuple  = {row,m_colIndex[row][col]};
          array<int, 2> A_T_tuple  = {row,A_T.m_colIndex[row][col]};
          if (A_T[A_T_tuple] == this->operator[](A_tuple))
            {
              is_symmetric = true;
            }
...
```

Added some more code for clarity.

Here is the error message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SparseMatrix::operator[](std::__1::array<int, 2ul>&) const", referenced from:
      SparseMatrix::symmetric() const in SparseMatrix.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments, and the problem is in code which was not posted

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct, that `this` implements `operator[]`? If so use `this->operator[](/*arguments*/)` instead of `this->[]`

Answer (score 0):

Just put the asterisk inside of the braces:

```
(*this)[some_index];
```

This is needed because dereference operator `*` has a lower precedence than a subscript operator.

---

For updated question:

You seem to have a `const` version of the `operator[]` declared but not defined, given that you are getting a link error and not a compilation error. You need to provide a body for this `operator[]() const` so you can use it from your `symmetric` method. You cannot use a non-const operator from a const method.

Comment: That did almost compile.  This is the error I am getting.       "SparseMatrix::operator[](std::__1::array<int, 2ul>&) const", referenced from:
      SparseMatrix::symmetric() const in SparseMatrix.o

Comment: @Zachary42, please provide a more complete error message.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SparseMatrix::operator[](std::__1::array<int, 2ul>&) const", referenced from:
      SparseMatrix::symmetric() const in SparseMatrix.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The accessor is non const and I'v already been using it so I know it works.

Comment: @Zachary42, it seems that you have a `const` accessor declared but not defined (no body). You can't use a non-const accessor from a const method `symmetric`.

Comment: I added the symmetric function prototype, it is a const function.  So you are saying I cannot use a non-const accessor like my accessor from a const method? I'm fairly new to c++ so excuse my sophomoric questions.

Comment: @Zachary42 Yes, the `const` method can't use non-`const` methods, because there is implicit `const SparseMatrix* this` parameter, but you want to call a method with non-const this